# PHP: Unidentified Index with NULL value

Tags: php, null, notice

I've tried everything but just can't get this notice to disappear.

I have a `text input` that display's the content of `$variable` which is being grabbed from a database and either has value of NULL or an integer value.

When the value is NULL, and I use this, I get **1 error** of unidentified index.

```
if(isset($data['variable'])) { $variable = $data['variable']; }
else { $variable = numberFormat($data['variable']); }
```

When the value is NULL, and I use this, I get **2 errors** of unidentified index.

```
if($data['variable'] == NULL) { $variable = $data['variable']; } 
else { $variable = numberFormat($data['variable']); }
```

Can anyone shed some light to how to get rid of these "notices"? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you attempting to operate on the value at this index when you have already determined it does not exist?

Comment: Is numberFormat your own function? Can you post the code? Or did you mean number_format?

Comment: Well, seems pretty clear to me. `isset()` returns `false` if the element you specify doesn't exist. But if the array doesn't exist either, it will give you errors (because you're trying to access a element from an unexistant variable). First check if the array exists and then if the element exists. `if (isset($data) && isset($data['variable'])) { /* do your thing */ }`.

Comment: Also the first script seems weird. `if (isset($data['variable'])) { /* here $data['variable'] exists */ } else { /* here $data['variable'] doesn't exist, why are you trying to read it? */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to see if the `$data` variable is available.  If that is null, then you can't access an element inside a non-existent variable.

```
if (isset($data)) {
    if(isset($data['variable'])) { $variable = $data['variable']; }
    else {
        //THIS MAKES NO SENSE. $data['variable'] does not exist.
        //$variable = numberFormat($data['variable']);
        //You can put something else in here, however
        $variable = "";
    } 
}
```

Secondly, accessing `$data['variable']` when it does not exist is non-sensical because... well I doesn't exist!

Comment: Thanks Kirk, but the $data variable is available. It's a `mysql_fetch_array` that I use to get previous information before this.

Comment: @bryan Sorry, I missed the second part.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Why does that make no sense? It does exist it just holds no value (yet). I either want my input box displaying nothing at all (NULL) or format the integer that the variable holds.

Comment: @bryan You can put something else in the `$variable` variable.  I updated the code to put an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `$data['variable']` does not exist. You get 2 errors in the second example, because you didn't use `isset()`, which can handle unset variables.

Answer (score 0):

`null` values aren't retrieved from a MySQL database, so any variable that might contain one is not set.

In your first snippet you're testing for this, but go ahead and assign the value anyway, so you get a notice.

```
if(isset($data['variable'])) {
  $variable = $data['variable'];
} else { 
  $variable = numberFormat($data['variable']); // Test for isset() fails, code comes here.
}
```

You need to assign something meaningful to $variable in your `else` clause since `$data['variable']` is not set.

Comment: It is set, it just holds a NULL value in the database.

Comment: No - null values aren't returned. It's not set.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$variable = (isset($data['variable'])) ? $data['variable'] : 0;
```